# How to show “conditionally unbiased” and “consistency” and “asymptotically distribution” in this regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, unbiased-estimator, consistency

[image]

Hi guys, I am wondering about this regression.

How to show that the β ̃is conditionally unbiased and consistent?

And how to find the asymptotically distribution of β ̃?

Please tell me how this can do, I appreciate any help of you, thanks in advance.

Comment: This estimate must be biased for $c\ne 0,$ as you can see by examining any ridge regression trace plot.  However, it must be asymptotically *unbiased* because as $n$ grows, in most asymptotic formulations $X^\prime X$ eventually overwhelms $cI_k$ and $\tilde\beta$ therefore approaches the OLS estimator, which is known to be unbiased.